# Using Persistence APIs with Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been developing and application and I create all the web services using google endpoints.

For default is using Cloud DataStorage, and i want to change it to Cloud SQL storage. I'm following this steps from the documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

    ...
        // Set the persistence driver and url based on environment, production or local.
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap();
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
              SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
          properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",
              "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
          properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",
              "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/demo");
        } else {
          properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",
              "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",
              "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo");
        }

        // Create a EntityManager which will perform operations on the database.

PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(propertiesMap, "persistence-unit-name");
```

What "persistence-unit-name" means in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

As per the definition, A persistence unit defines a set of all entity classes that are managed by EntityManager instances in an application.

Please refer to the following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbrj/index.html) for more details.

Now, once your application is built and since this is a web application, as per the link above "If you package the persistence unit as a set of classes in a WAR file, persistence.xml should be located in the WAR file’s WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory." Look inside the `META-INF` folder under `src` directory and you should see a `persistence.xml` file, which will have the persistent unit name defined as the one you specified while getting the PMF.

Hope this helps.